# CURL request some float values are different when accessed from caller compared to originater

Tags: php, json, curl

something strange is happening with a CURL request I have. The request is sent from domainA to domainB, in order to get prices from domainB.

DomainB returns JSON, and when viewing this JSON directly from the endpoint at domainB, and comparing the values to what is being received when calling from domainA, some float's values change.

The json structure is as follows (dummy data and part of bigger structure):

```
"name":"some name",
"prices": [
        {
          "price": 11.5,
          "currency": "GBP"
        },
        {
          "price": 12.5,
          "currency": "EUR"
        },
        {
          "price": 5.5,
          "currency": "AUD"
        },
        {
          "price": 9.5,
          "currency": "USD"
        },
        {
          "price": 4.5,
          "currency": "CAD"
        }
      ]
```

The values that are changing is the price property in the example. Note that there are allot of different categories for products, and each product inside the categories has a price property which is an array like above.

The changing values aren't consistent either, only two of the 10+ products' prices change, these two are the first items in their respective categories.

The kicker - These values have been changed to strings but the exact same happened.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: From the origin host - are you able to view the prices correctly? Are they being pulled from database w/o conversion? your question isn't clear.
Looks to me like maybe at the origin host, you are iterating through the Dataset, and maybe something there is wrong when you output the result to json

Comment: Sorry for the question being a bit unclear. From the origin host the prices are correct, the base price is pulled from the database and conversions done on it which builds the above structure. When viewing the json that the origin host outputs directly, the values are as expected, but when comparing to the json i get from the caller, the values have changed, and not all of them, it's only for two products. For more info, i just do a basic curl request with auth to get the information, and both domains have ssl certificates

Comment: If you want to save floting values presicion inside a json, use strings. You wrote "These values have been changed to strings" — changed where?

Comment: As in the prices returned from the origin host were converted to strings before sending the response but the prices still changed. I have no idea how that's even possible as it's strings but the exact same happened. The only thins I can think of now is to revert to casting all floats to strings again and see if it maybe changed